# Flutter EmailJS blank white screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, forms, email

In flutter EmailJS I tested the code it loads a white screen on my Android test device and emulator. What am I missing and why is it doing this. Please explain I am learning Flutter so please give step by step if you can so I will understand. Also, how do you fit a widget with app bar into this code.

Below is the whole code.

```
   import 'dart:convert';
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {}

     Future sendEmail({
     required String name,
     required String email,
     required String subject,
     required String message,
     }) async {

    // put in the ID here below
    final serviceId = '';
     final templateId = '';
     final userId = '';

     final url = Uri.parse('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send');
     final response = await http.post(
     url,
     headers: {
      'origin': 'http://localhost',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: json.encode({
      'service_id': serviceId,
      'template_id': templateId,
      'user_id': userId,
      'template_params': {
        'user_name': name,
        'user_email': email,
        'user_subject': subject,
        'user_message': message,
      },
    }),

  );
}
```

I expected to see a contact form instead a white screen in android test device and emulator, I am using Visual Studio Code.